# regular expression in split function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I make ajax request to receive a text file.
I need to read this text in javascript.

The Text file is  like this:

---

> kjnggnfgnfkjg
>
> as "bob"
>
> bs "alice"
>
> fmdklfmdlkfk
>
> as "Marc"
>
> bs "Julien"
>
> dfdlf ..

---

I need to create two array, one with the line that begin with `'as'` and the second with the line that begin with `'bs'` word. Every element of array doesn't need to have the `'as'` or `'bs'` word as well as "". in this case:

```
a=[bob,Marc] and b=[alice,julien]
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Share the code you tried please?

Comment: I just tried with the data that I receive from ajax request:
i use data.split(''\n") in order to read every line...
but I'm not able to make a select with the regular expression...

function obtain(){
   $.ajax({url:"../local/exampleText",
             dataType:"Text",
             success:function(data){b=data.split("\n");
                                                   console.log(data)}});
}

Comment: Ok, just share your code and tell us what regex did you tried, so we can help you.

Comment: somthing like this:
split(\n.^as | ^bs);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have split the text in lines, you can filter and map those :

```
var lines = t.split('\n');
var asPattern = /^as \"(\w+)\"$/;
var bsPattern = /^bs \"(\w+)\"$/;
a = lines.filter(l => l.match(asPattern))
         .map(l => l.replace(asPattern, "$1"));
b = lines.filter(l => l.match(bsPattern))
         .map(l => l.replace(bsPattern, "$1"));
```

---

`list.filter(predicate)` will return a sublist of the items matching the predicate. Here we use a lambda function as the predicate, which will return true only if the line match the pattern.

```
>lines
["kjnggnfgnfkjg", "", "as "bob"", "", "bs "alice"", "", "fmdklfmdlkfk", "", "as "Marc"", "", "bs "Julien"", "", "dfdlf"]
>lines.filter(l => l.match(/^as \"(\w+)\"$/))
["as "bob"", "as "Marc""]
```

---

`list.map(transformationFunction)` will return a list of the results of the application of a transformation function to each element of the initial list. Here we reuse the same pattern and use its first group as a replacement.

```
>filteredLines
["as "bob"", "as "Marc""]
>filteredLines.map(l => l.replace(/^as \"(\w+)\"$/, "$1"))
["bob", "Marc"]
```